# how to count dot number in a string in oracle

Tags: sql, regex

I have string like this 125.67.888.66.123. I want to count number of dot operations.

For example:

123.45 => 2

3446.67.88 => 3

23.45.567.88 => 4

I write this query    `SELECT REGEXP_COUNT ('3.222.123.44.1055', '.') FROM dual;`

But it gives 16.How can i obtain 5 for above query.When i find exact number I will start a loop.Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `.` -- and to add `1`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT('3.222.123.44.1055', '[.]') + 1
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Like said Gordon, you need to escape the dot, because it's a special char in a regex.

But I'm not agree with the regex, to escape you have to use a backslash.

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT('3.222.123.44.1055', '\.') +1 
FROM dual;
```